# Local Storage - Phone out of space

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser, ionic-framework

I have used the Ionic framework to build my App and have been thinking about the local storage and how it works. One of my users phone storage is capped out with photos and video content, and I was wondering how this would effect an HTML5 App that uses local storage.

I decided to test it by purchasing a cheap phone with only 2GB internal storage, and filling it up with random Audio files from my PC. I have managed to get Windows to think there is 0kb left in internal storage, yet my Ionic App can still add data to local storage.

[image: 0kb Screenshot in explorer]

[image: 0kb Screenshot in properties]

Does anyone know why this is, or have any input as to where local storage actually is saved? I sort of expected it to just store in the browsers App Data, but maybe it is somewhere else?

**EDIT**

Have just looked at the phone storage and it says there is still 99.9mb that is un-used. Android must not let Windows fill all of the device's storage. Does anyone still have any knowledge on what would happen if I managed to fill this last 99mb??

[image: 99mb Screenshot from phone]

Comment: It is certainly possible that the browser pre-allocates some file space to use for locaStorage so that it never has to deal with out of disk space issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.. I cleared my App data and then managed to fill up the last 99mb of space by duplicating more files using the `File Commander` App on the phone.

I then opened my Ionic App and logged in (which downloads about 1.5mb of App data) and the App seemed to work fine (as everything was stored in RAM at the time). Once the App closed and I re-opened it, all the stored data was gone (as there was no space to move it to from RAM I am guessing)

**End result:** App works fine in RAM but if there is no space in localStorage, it will not error or tell you it didn't work, it will just not save the data.

**Note:** I have not tested this when there has been existing data in App, and trying to add to it which would take the phone over the storage limit. Im unsure if this would corrupt the existing data or just not let you add to it.

Comment: As far as i know cordova reserves for you 10 mb of ram whilst you install an app